# How to particular extract information from a text file

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy, text

I have many texts file with the given format (It won’t be exactly this format line by line; I am showing some parts from one file to understand the general format).

```
 C:\seismo\2008\07\2008-07-03-2055-56S.HP____030                      
  2008 7 3205556 BNJR  tc  16.1  f  1.5  s/n  4.0  Q  101  corr -0.89  rms 0.18
  2008 7 3205556 BNJR  tc  16.1  f  3.0  s/n  2.9  Q  290  corr -0.80  rms 0.20
  2008 7 3205556 BNJR  tc  16.1  f  8.0  s/n  3.9  Q  695  corr -0.63  rms 0.37
  2008 7 3205556 BNJR  tc  16.1  f 12.0  s/n  8.1  Q  913  corr -0.67  rms 0.39
  2008 7 3205556 BNJR  tc  16.1  f 16.0  s/n  5.7  Q 1435  corr -0.58  rms 0.42
 C:\seismo\2008\07\2008-07-03-2055-56S.HP____030                      
  2008 7 3205556 BNJR  tc  16.1  f  1.5  s/n  7.9  Q  150  corr -0.78  rms 0.19
  2008 7 3205556 BNJR  tc  16.1  f  3.0  s/n  5.3  Q  190  corr -0.86  rms 0.24
  2008 7 3205556 BNJR  tc  16.1  f  5.0  s/n  2.3  Q  401  corr -0.64  rms 0.39
  2008 7 3205556 BNJR  tc  16.1  f  8.0  s/n  3.1  Q  673  corr -0.65  rms 0.37
  2008 7 3205556 BNJR  tc  16.1  f 16.0  s/n  3.8  Q 1320  corr -0.64  rms 0.39
 C:\seismo\2008\07\2008-07-24-1124-44S.HP____012                      
 C:\seismo\2008\07\2008-07-24-1124-44S.HP____012                      
  2008 724112444 BNJR  tc   9.3  f  1.5  s/n  2.7  Q  119  corr -0.82  rms 0.21
  2008 724112444 BNJR  tc   9.3  f  3.0  s/n  2.3  Q  286  corr -0.68  rms 0.29
 C:\seismo\2008-10-21-1507-30S.__053                                    
 C:\seismo\2008-10-21-1544-56S.__033                                    
 C:\seismo\2008-10-21-1544-56S.__033                                    
 C:\seismo\2008-10-21-1544-56S.__033                                    
 C:\seismo\2008-10-21-1742-39S.NSN___015                                    
 C:\seismo\2008-10-21-1742-39S.NSN___015 
 C:\seismo\2010-11-18-1111-12S.NSN___027                                    
  20101118111112 BNJR  tc  20.2  f  1.5  s/n  2.6  Q  141  corr -0.79  rms 0.20
  20101118111112 BNJR  tc  20.2  f  3.0  s/n  6.6  Q  292  corr -0.58  rms 0.37
  20101118111112 BNJR  tc  20.2  f  5.0  s/n  3.4  Q  894  corr -0.54  rms 0.23
 C:\seismo\2011-02-01-2130-40S.NSN___027                                    
 C:\seismo\2011-02-04-0333-36S.NSN___027                                    
 C:\seismo\2011-02-04-0333-36S.NSN___027
```

Which is showing the file path of certain files with their content in it, if the file doesn’t have required content, it only shows the path of the file.
[image]

The information (variables) I have marked with a red rectangle is the key information I have to search for whether the file is not listed in the above file or not. If it is listed, the content needs to extract too.
I am looking for a way to extract the path and its content shown in the file respective to the information I have (red rectangle). While extracting the content I want to specifically extract the columns marked with black rectangle.

I made a function to extract lines/multiple lines with respect to a line containing specific string. Since the content following each path has different number of lines this function seems useless in my problem.

```
def extract_lines(file,linenumbers,endline=None):
    '''Extract a line /multiple lines from a text file
    line number should be considered as starting from zero.    
    '''
    
    with open(file, encoding='utf8') as f:
        content = f.readlines()                  
    lines=[]     
    if ((type(linenumbers) is int) or (all([isinstance(item, int) for item in linenumbers]))):
        
        if type(linenumbers) is list:
            for idx,item in enumerate(linenumbers):
                lines.append(content[item])
                
        elif ((endline is None) and (type(linenumbers) is int)):
            lines.append(content[linenumbers])
        
        elif ((type(endline) is int) and (type(linenumbers) is int)):
            for item in np.arange(linenumbers,endline):
                lines.append(content[item])                   
        else:
            print('Error in linenumbers input')
            
    lines=[s.replace('\t',' ') for s in lines]
    lines=[s.strip('\n') for s in lines]            
    return lines
```

How to perform with this task using python?

Comment: Can you use pandas?

Comment: I'm not sure I have the format right... you have a `s.replace('\t',' ') for s in lines` but I don't see any tabs in the data. Are those fields space delimited or tab delimited?

Comment: @tdelaney   Yes. Those are tabs

Comment: Please supply an example of your desired output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This file has fixed columns, so you need to fetch your data using column numbers.

```
#0123456789-123456789-123456789-123456789-123456789-123456789-123456789-123456789-
#  2008 7 3205556 BNJR  tc  16.1  f  1.5  s/n  4.0  Q  101  corr -0.89  rms 0.18

for ln in open('x.txt'):
    # Is this a file line or a data line?
    if ln[1] != ' ':
        curfile = ln.strip()
    else:
        # Grab date and time.
        dt = ln[2:14].replace(' ','0')
        # Grab the 2-digit code.
        dc = ln[14:16]
        # Grab site code
        site = ln[17:21]
        # Grab the 'f' code.
        f = float(ln[34:39].strip())
        # Grab the 'Q' code.
        q = int(ln[52:56].strip())

        print(f"{dt},{dc},{site},{f},{q}")
```

Output:

```
200807032055,56,BNJR,1.5,10
200807032055,56,BNJR,3.0,29
200807032055,56,BNJR,8.0,69
200807032055,56,BNJR,12.0,91
200807032055,56,BNJR,16.0,143
200807032055,56,BNJR,1.5,15
200807032055,56,BNJR,3.0,19
200807032055,56,BNJR,5.0,40
200807032055,56,BNJR,8.0,67
200807032055,56,BNJR,16.0,132
200807241124,44,BNJR,1.5,11
200807241124,44,BNJR,3.0,28
201011181111,12,BNJR,1.5,14
201011181111,12,BNJR,3.0,29
201011181111,12,BNJR,5.0,89
```

Comment: How to read a specific number of lines instead of reading all lines?

Comment: When do you want to stop?  Do you want to stop when it reads a certain date?  (You can figure that out by comparing the `dt` string.)   If you really want to stop after a count, then you use a counter.

Answer (score 0):

Its hard to tell from the data posted, but I think this is tab separated data. The first column either has a file name or is empty. You want to group the data without a file name with the file name above it. `itertools.groupby` can do this. Have it start a new group on each non-empty first column. As a note, you could do this in pandas also by using its `read_csv` and its `groupby` method.

In the example, I put the groupby code in a generator function. This makes it usable in more than one place and reduces nesting. Alternately, you could replace the `yield` with your own code and skip the extra function.

```
import itertools
import csv

def extract_records(filename):
    """Yield (filename, list_of_rows) pairs from file"""
    found_filename = None
    with open(filename, encoding="utf8", newline="") as file:
        reader = csv.reader(file, dialect="excel-tab")
        for is_filename, rows in itertools.groupby(reader,
                lambda row: not row[0].strip()):
            if is_filename:
                found_filename = list(rows)[0][0] # only row, first column
            else:
                assert found_filename is not None, "filename precedes values"
                yield found_filename, list(rows)

for filename, values in extract_records("test.txt"):
    print(filename, values)
```